# what is the best prectice of declaring variable in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Sometime I have to declare variables in Spring controller.As spring controllers are like beans that are created only at start,then it is necessary that variable declared in controller should be static.I know that static may utilize more memory at they are not garbage collected.
I have two options to declare variable in Spring controller,I want suggestions about which one is better.

**Suggestion One:**

```
@Controller
@requestMapping("parent")
public Class ControllerClazz{
  private String varible ="ABC";

}
```

**Suggestion Two:**

```
@Controller
@requestMapping("parent")
public Class ControllerClazz{
  private static String varible ="ABC";

}
```

What are pros and cons above two suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Spring MVC `controllers` are singletons by default. An object field will be shared and visible for all requests and all sessions forever.

However without any `synchronization` you might run into all sorts of `concurrency` issues (race conditions, visibility). Thus your field should have `volatile` (and `private`, by the way) modifier to avoid visibility issues.

In `Spring` you can use request- (see [4.5.4.2 Request scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session)) and session-scoped (see: [4.5.4.3 Session scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session)) beans. You can inject them to controllers and any other beans (even singletons!), but Spring makes sure each request/session has an independent instance.

Answer (score 4):

The nature of spring controllers is to be a single component managed by a IOC container (similar to servlets in Servlet API) so the best practice is not to have any variables except those which handles references to other components injected by a IOC container.

In your case try to externalize your variable into a separate class and also do not forget to use final modifier if the variable is never going to change. In case your variable is going to change consider usage of java.util.concurrent capabilities.

Also always try to stick to [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)